# Update prop for dynamically inserted element

Tags: node.js, reactjs

New to react... Really banging my head against it with this one... I'm trying to figure out how to get a dynamically inserted component to update when the props are changed. I've assigned it to a parent state object but it doesn't seem to re-render. I've read that this is what's supposed to happen.
I was using ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode to re-render the specific elements I needed to, but it kept yelling at me with red text.

I need to hide "chat.message" unless the user has the authority to see it (server just sends empty string), but I still need to render the fact that **it exists**, and reveal it should the user get authentication. I'm using a css transition to reveal it, but I really need a good way to update the chat.message prop easily.

```js
renderChats(uuid){

  let userState = this.state.userStates.find(user => {
    return user.uuid === uuid;
  });
  const children = userState.chats.map((chat) => {
    let ChatReactElement = this.getChatMarkup(chat.cuid, chat.message, chat.status);
    return ChatReactElement;
  });
  ReactDOM.render(children, document.getElementById(`chats-${this.state.guid}-${uuid}`));
}
```

getChatMarkup() just returns JSX and inserts Props... I feel like state should be getting passed along here. Even when I use a for-loop and insert the state explicitly, it doesn't seem to re-render on changes.

```js
getChatMarkup(cuid, message, status){
  return(
    <BasicChatComponent
      key={cuid} 
      cuid={cuid}
      message={message}
      status={status}
    />        
  );
}
```

I attempted to insert some code line this:

```js
renderChats(uuid){

  let userState = this.state.userStates.find(user => {
    return user.uuid === uuid;
  });
  const children = userState.chats.map((chat) => {
    let ChatReactElement = this.getChatMarkup(chat.cuid, chat.message, chat.status);
    if(chat.status.hidden) 
      this.setState({ hiddenChatRE: [ ...this.state.hiddenChatRE, ChatReactElement ] }); // <== save elements
    return ChatReactElement;
  });
  ReactDOM.render(children, document.getElementById(`chats-${this.state.guid}-${uuid}`));
}
```

and later in my code:

```js
this.state.hiddenChatRE.every(ReactElement => {
  if(ReactElement.key == basicChats[chatIndex].cuid){
    ReactElement.props = {
      ... //completely invalid code
    }
  }
});
```

The only response I see here is my ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(); approach...
Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

Although perhaps I should be kicking myself, I read up on how React deals with **keys** on their components. So there's actually a fairly trivial answer here if anyone comes looking... Just call your render function again *after you update the state*.

In my case, something like:

```js
this.setState(state =>({
  ...state,
    userStates : state.userStates.map((userstate) => {
      if(userstate.uuid == basicChats[chatIndex].uuid) return {
        ...userstate, 
        chats: userstate.chats.map((chat) => {
          if(chat.cuid == basicChats[chatIndex].cuid){
            //
            return { 
              cuid: basicChats[chatIndex].cuid, 
              message: basicChats[chatIndex].message, 
              status: basicChats[chatIndex].status 
            }
          }
          else return chat;
        })
      }
      else return userstate;
    })
}));
```

and then, elsewhere in my example:

```js
this.state.userStates.map((userstate) => {
  this.renderChats(userstate.uuid);
});
```

Other than the fact that I'd recommend using indexed arrays for this example to cut complexity, this is the solution, and works. This is because even though it feels like you'd end up with duplicates (that was my intuition), the *uid* on the BasicChatComponent itself makes all the difference, letting react know to only re-render those specific elements.